# Can a part-identification tag be added?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

I don't have the rep (nor the familiarity with this particular se site), but my question: [What is the name of this part on a 2003 Mazda Protege5?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/785/508) reminds me of the `[story-identification]` tagged questions on the scifi.stackexchange.com.

Maybe a `[part-identification]` tag should be added?

Comment: Can you give a little bit more background on how this tag adds value?  Perhaps a couple examples will help me understand how this is helpful?

Comment: The question I asked on the parent site is a good example: the identification question answer usually accompanies another question which I have at the bottom of the question.  A question that, on its own, may  add value to the site. Maybe not mine in that form, but the many of 'follow-up' questions would add value on their own but not so much if it's buried in an identification question.

Comment: I guess I can also mention the normal uses of tags: driving RSS feeds and for adding to the "Ignored Tag" set. I think a  [part-identification] tag would typically be used by those inexperienced in motor vehicle repair/maintenance (like me) so some expert/specialist users to this site will want to filter them out--maybe not so much early on with a few hundred questions, but probably as it matures and there are more questions to sort out.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying.  I think this could be a beneficial tag.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I added the tag as you requested, tagging [your question](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/785/what-is-the-name-of-this-part-on-a-2003-mazda-protege5) as well as [What does this device on a 1985 Mercury Lynx/Ford Export Diesel do?](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/608/what-does-this-device-on-a-1985-mercury-lynx-ford-export-diesel-do)

I am not sure if the tag will be beneficial or not, we can let the community decide by using or not using it, and discussing it here. We can always take it away later if it doesn't benefit the site.

I would ask that you edit the tag wiki so that others know what the tag is for and how to best use it. I know you don't have the enough rep, I will approve it once it's done. I would also suggest adding a link to this question in the body of the tag wiki, in case someone has a question or wants to discuss it's use.

Comment: thanks, that was fast.  although, it was more of a suggestion since I'm definitely not an expert.  I was thinking the actual experts who would be using this site daily would decide.  hopefully, they'll chime in at some point in the future.